# Evaluating the Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos\big(2x^2\big)\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to compute the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos\big(2x^2\big) dx$$

I am wondering if there's a nice closed form of this elegant integral. I have tried to compute this integral using some substitutions, Laplace and Mellin transforms, however it doesn't seem to get or transform to something more simplified.

Any approach (including complex analysis) is most welcomed.

Thanks.

**EDIT $\textbf{1}$:** @heropup has provided a beautiful answer, however I would be much more happy if there's another nice way to prove the same. Thanks.

Comment: Converges by comparison (I think we all know that). But perhaps an appropriate contour does the job.

Comment: Mathematica says it should be $\sqrt{\frac{(1+\sqrt{5})\pi}{10}} \approx 1.008$

Comment: Seems interesting, I'm wondering if there's a nice way to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Gaussian integral?

Comment: In short, Yeah but I'm not much comfortable with it.

Comment: Amusingly the value can be written as $\sqrt{\frac{\pi \phi}{5}}$, where $\phi$ as usual is the golden ratio.

Answer (score 6):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to do something like this:  $$e^{-x^2} \cos (2x^2) = e^{-x^2} \frac{e^{2x^2 i} + e^{-2x^2 i}}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left( e^{-(1-2i)x^2} + e^{-(1+2i)x^2} \right),$$ then use the fact that $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$ to evaluate $$\int_{x=0}^\infty e^{-zx^2} \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{z}}, \quad \Re(z) > 0.$$  Then we obtain $$\int_{x=-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \cos (2x^2) \, dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \left((1-2i)^{-1/2} + (1+2i)^{-1/2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{10} \pi}.$$

---

In case that last step is unclear, one simply writes
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2i}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2i}} = \frac{\sqrt{1 + 2i} + \sqrt{1 - 2i}}{\sqrt{5}}.$$  Then because $$1 \pm 2i = \sqrt{5} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} i\right) = \sqrt{5} e^{\pm i \theta}$$ where $\theta = \tan^{-1} 2$, we have $$\sqrt{1 + 2i} + \sqrt{1 - 2i} = 5^{1/4}(e^{i\theta/2} + e^{-i\theta/2}) = 2 \cdot 5^{1/4} \cos \frac{\theta}{2} = 2 \cdot 5^{1/4} \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos \theta}{2}} \\ = 2 \cdot 5^{1/4} \sqrt{\frac{1 + 1/\sqrt{5}}{2}}.$$  The rest is algebra.  I believe such a computation should be accessible to a student of complex analysis--indeed, a student of high school trigonometry and complex number arithmetic.

Comment: That's great. Can you prove it without using integral representation of $\sqrt{\pi}$?

Comment: @BooleanWick Why don't you try it for yourself?  Now that you have seen one way to do it, I think it might be interesting for you to explore other techniques.

Comment: Sure. Also could you please elaborate your last step? I'm not sure how you reached it. Thanks.

Comment: @BooleanWick Basically he just split the integral into two integrals, one from $0$ to $\infty$ and one from $-\infty$ to $0$, and then you can apply the substitution $u = -x$ on the second integral to get the same integral from $0$ to $\infty$. Do you see now?

Comment: @StephenDonovan You have an alternate proof using Gaussian Integral?

Comment: @BooleanWick My idea ran along very similar lines to this one, except mine involved substituting $e^{-x^2}\cos(2x^2) = Re(e^{x^2(-1+2i)})$, and then pulling the real-part operator out of the integral. I have an alternative idea using the Leibniz rule I'm working on though

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your time and efforts. You should answer it once you reach the expression.

Comment: @BooleanWick Okay the Leibniz rule version I was thinking of isn't exactly working, it gets really gross really fast. This one seems like the way to go.

Comment: I see, any other approach? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using the gaussian integral
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos\big(2x^2\big)\, dx=\Re\Bigg[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(1-2 i) x^2}\,dx\Bigg]$$
$$I=\Re \Bigg[\sqrt{\frac \pi {1-2i}}\Bigg]=\sqrt \pi\,\Re \Bigg[\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2 i}{5}}\Bigg]=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{\sqrt[4]{5}}\, \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \tan ^{-1}(2)\right)$$ Finally
$$I=\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{10} \, \pi }$$

Comment: @BooleanWick. Yes, it does